# Assigning values of one entire datagrid to another in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

am a newbie to C# and wpf. 
Now regarding my problem, I have two wpf windows and each has a datagrid tool. I dynamically populate the value of the datarid. What i want to do is, on the click of a button i want to replicate the values of the datagrid in current window to the datagrid in next wpf window. Kindly guide me.

I am passing the datagrid of the current window to the next window using parameterized constructor.

```
        Bill b = new Bill(dataGrid1);
        this.Close();
        b.Show();
```

And in the Bill window am receiving it in the constructor.

```
     public Bill(DataGrid temp)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //have to do something here

    }
```

and now with the received object i need to populate the datagrid in the current window.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried?
What you are asking is possible but we need some code from your end to help you better.

Comment: Can you bind both views to the same viewmodel?

Comment: @AnandMurali have added the code.

Comment: Its not necessary to pass the DataGrid object to the next window. How are you generating the columns, in XAML or in Codebehind? What are you assigning to ItemSource property of dataGrid1?

Comment: @AnandMurali am generating the columns in the codebehind. am using the datagrid1.items.add() function to add the columns. Am not using the itemsource property, generating all the rows using the fucntion only.

Answer (score 1):

using a datatable solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like...

TheOtherGrid.DataSource = temp.DataSource;
TheOtherGrid.DataBind;

Comment: There is no property called `DataSource` in `DataGrid`, you mean `ItemSource` right?

Comment: My bad - I was thinking of the gridview in a asp.net.  I'm not sure what its called in WPF's datagrid but your probably correct with itemsource.